# C# Object/object

Tags: c#, object

Is C# `Object`/`object` a value-type or reference type?

I examined that they can keep references but this references can't be used to change objects.

```
using System;

class MyClass
{
    public static void Swap(Object obj1, Object obj2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("After Swapping");
        obj1 = 100;
        obj2 = 200;
    }
}

class MainClass 
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        Object obj1 = new Object ();
        obj1 = 10;

        Object obj2 = new Object ();
        obj2 = 20;

        Console.WriteLine(obj1.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(obj2.ToString());

        MyClass.Swap(obj1, obj2);

        Console.WriteLine(obj1.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(obj2.ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post some code that demonstrate you cannot change object references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changes you make in `Swap` are limited to there - you're only playing with pointers (and boxing), the references outside the function stay the same (you have 4 references). You'll see the difference if you changed the signature of your method:

try `Swap(ref Object obj1, ref Object obj2)`.

Same goes for

```
Object obj1 = new Object ();
obj1 = 10;
```

This isn't better than `Object obj1 = 10;`, by the way

To see object is really a references type, use a class with properties, for example:

```
class Foo {
   public int Value {get; set;}
}
```

Change the `Value` of the object in `Swap`, and you will see the effects on your main program.

Answer (score 5):

It's a reference type - if you look at the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.aspx), you'll see it's declared as a class. All classes are reference types.

And yes, the same is true for `System.ValueType` and `System.Enum` - they're both reference types as well, despite the names... value types derive from them though.

EDIT: Your update shows that what you're really confused by is parameter passing. See my articles on [parameter passing in C#](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) and [reference/value types](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/references.html).

Comment: I never knew that System.ValueType was itself a reference type... I always assumed it was a value type. It looks like it was made a reference type so that Equals() and GetHashCode() could be overridden to compare content.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that

```
 Object obj1 = new Object ();
 obj1 = 10;
```

is the same as:

```
Object obj1 = 10;
```

Because the compiler intervenes with 'boxing' to turn the value-type `int` into a reference type. And inside your Swap method you are boxing again, overwriting the reference parameters.

So Kobi's and Dreamwalker's solution, using ref parameters, will actually work:

```
 public static void Swap(ref Object obj1, ref Object obj2) // Use keyword 'ref'
```

But it is far from ideal.

A better solution would be a generic method:

```
 static void Swap<T>(ref T x, ref T y)
 {
    T z = x;  x = y;  y = z;
 }
```

So the compiler can generate the most appropriate code for reference- and value-types.

Answer (score 0):

as `object` is mother of all objects it is a reference type

Answer (score 0):

Your should write code like this:

```
using System;

class MyClass
{
    public static void Swap(ref Object obj1, ref Object obj2) // Use keyword 'ref'
    {
        Console.WriteLine("After Swapping");
        obj1 = 100;
        obj2 = 200;
    }
}

class MainClass 
{
    static void Main(string[] args) 
    {
        Object obj1 = new Object ();
        obj1 = 10;

        Object obj2 = new Object ();
        obj2 = 20;

        Console.WriteLine(obj1.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(obj2.ToString());

        MyClass.Swap(ref obj1, ref obj2); // Use keyword 'ref'

        Console.WriteLine(obj1.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(obj2.ToString());

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

You can read more information about keyword 'ref' in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

Quote from MSDN:

> Passing Parameters (C# Programming
>   Guide)
>
> In C#, parameters can be passed either
>   by value or by reference. Passing
>   parameters by reference enables
>   function members, methods, properties,
>   indexers, operators, and constructors
>   to change the value of the parameters
>   and have that change persist. To pass
>   a parameter by reference, use the ref
>   or out keyword. For simplicity, only
>   the ref keyword is used in the
>   examples in this topic. For more
>   information about the difference
>   between ref and out, see ref (C#
>   Reference), out (C# Reference), and
>   Passing Arrays Using ref and out (C#
>   Programming Guide). For example:

```
// Passing by value
static void Square(int x)
{
    // code...
}
// Passing by reference
static void Square(ref int x)
{
    // code...
}
```

(c) [MSDN - Passing Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

It's because the runtime type of obj1 and obj2 is `System.Int32` (check with `obj1.GetType().ToString()`), that is, a value type. No reference copy is made in your Swap function. Instead it just performs boxing and unboxing operations, which have no effect on the real variables.

Comment: That wouldn't work for reference types either, not just for `int` - doing `obj1 = new Foo();` changes the reference locally on the function.